# Usages de « décommissionner » et « désaffecter »

Tags: usage, anglicismes

Est-ce que *décommissionner* est un anglicisme? Si oui, est-ce que *désaffecter* est à préconiser en lieu de? Est-ce qu'il porte la même signification? "Désaffecter" semble plutôt réservé à l'immobilier, tandis que "décommissionner" aux actifs/matériel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Commissionner*, au sens de *charger **quelqu'un** d'une fonction* étant un verbe français et la construction dé + verbe étant légitime, je ne crois pas que l'on puisse parler d'anglicisme à son sujet.

Il est en revanche vrai que, contrairement à l'anglais, je ne l'ai jamais lu utilisé relativement à une entité non-humaine.

En CE sens, oui, cela deviendrait un anglicisme.

Relativement à une installation, un système qu'un anglais "would decommission", le français préfèrerait certainement : "***démanteler***".

Comment: *Décommissionner* est très utilisé aujourd'hui avec un sens très précis (retirer un matériel d'un ensemble dédié à un usage donné, en général parce qu'il a été remplacé par un matériel plus récent) et j'ai peur que *démanteler* (démonter, démolir, éparpiller façon puzzle...) soit trop fort et risque de provoquer quelques incompréhensions.

Comment: Oui jlliagre, tu as raison, il est devenu très utilisé aujourd'hui et en ce sens. Maintenant, comme le demandait l'OP, en ce sens, il s'agit d'un anglicisme. Quant à démanteler... certes... si Audiard s'en était emparé... cela aurait pu signifier vilain... maintenant je veux croire que l'on démantèle les centrales nucléaires... sans les faire pêter... ;)

Comment: Oui, on ne décommissionne pas une centrale nucléaire, ce qui peut prendre des dizaines d'années et comporte des inconnues comme le stockage des déchets de la même façon qu'on décommissionne un serveur informatique, opération de routine qui peut ne prendre que quelques minutes, voire secondes s'il est virtualisé...

Comment: La question m'est venue justement alors qu'on parlait de "décomissionner" un serveur virtuel au profit d'un autre! C'est vrai que "démanteler" semble fort un peu dans la mesure ou on remplace une composante d'une solution qui reste en opération, mais je préfère éviter l'utilisation d'anglicismes au travail lorsque c'est possible.

Answer (score 1):

C'est effectivement pour moi un anglicisme traduit en un mauvais néologisme.

*« Retiré du service »* pour l'informatique me semble le plus simple et adéquat.